# UIWebView plays inline without autoplay not work by using iframe

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, youtube-api

I search this issue these days, but I can't find the solution. I use youtube with iframe in UIWebview. I want to make it playsinline without auto play by following code

```
embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                     <html>\
                     <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>\
                     <script type='text/javascript'>\
                     function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\
                     {\
                     ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId')\
                     }\
                     </script>\
                     <iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=0' frameborder='0'>\
                     </body>\
                     </html>", (int)myWidth, (int)myHeight, _youtubeCode];
```

but it doesn't work. If using this code, then click webview to play the video, it allows to pop the video player to play the video.

I only success to play the video inline by following code, but it have to autoplay the video

```
 embedHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                               <html>\
                               <body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'>\
                               <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script>\
                               <script type='text/javascript'>\
                               function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()\
                               {\
                               ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerLiveId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})\
                               }\
                               function onPlayerReady(a)\
                               { \
                               a.target.playVideo(); \
                               }\
                               </script>\
                               <iframe id='playerLiveId' type='text/html' width='%d' height='%d' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/%@?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'>\
                               </body>\
                               </html>", (int)myWidth, (int)myHeight, _youtubeCode];
```

I need your help, please. btw, sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the following:

```
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
```

to your UIWebview code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If using Youtube API to play video, it can plays inline normally. But if user presses big red icon, the player will goes to full screen. I fixed it by adding an overlay view and remove it after playing.

```
UIView *overlayer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:ytWebView.bounds];
[overlayer setAutoresizingMask:(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth)];
[overlayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[ytWebView addSubview:overlayer];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(playVideo:)];
[overlayer addGestureRecognizer:tap];
self.overlayer = overlayer;
```

And inside your `playVideo:`, you use Youtube API to play video and remember to remove overlayer.
Hope that hep!